# Series convergence tests: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log^{100}n}{n}\sin\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do a convergence tests for the following series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log^{100}n}{n}\sin\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$$

I have one more question how can I show convergence with alternating series test (Leibniz's test)?

Comment: You can simplify the $\sin$: a known convergence test will appear.

Comment: It is usually recommended that you give your thoughts on the matter, so that your fellow users might be directed properly when answering your inquiry. It is also considered ungentle to use the imperative.

Comment: While Dirichlet's test is dandy, a beginning Calculus student might notice the $\sin$ terms give alternating signs, and then go on to use the Alternating Series Test, as hinted by Davide and Marvis.

Comment: Peter - you've right. I'm sorry but i'm not fluent in english especially math equation and i can't share my ideas how i can do this task. Thanks for answears, now i start analyze this and i hope so i understand this;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the Dirichlet's test (in fact the usual alternating test will do fine here) also termed the generalized alternating test. The test goes as follows. If we have a sequence of positive real numbers, $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and a sequence of complex numbers $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that

1. $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence i.e. $a_n > a_m$ whenever $m>n$.
2. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$.
3. $\left \lvert \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k\right \rvert \leq M$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $M$ is some constant independent of $n$

then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ converges.

Here let $a_n = \dfrac{\log^{100}n}{n}$ and $b_n = \sin \left(\dfrac{(2n+1) \pi}{2} \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Dirichlet's test: the seq. $$\,\left\{\frac{\log^{100}n}{n}\right\}\,$$ is monot. convergent to zero (after some adequate index and on), and the sequence of partial sums of the  series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi$$ is clearly bounded, thus the original series converges.

Comment: The last series is meaningless. Maybe you should be talking about the partial sums.

Comment: Of course, that's the intention. Although I wouldn't call that series "meaningless": divergent, yes.  Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$
\sin \frac{{\left( {2n + 1} \right)\pi }}
{2} = \left( { - 1} \right)^n 
$$
you can rewrite your series as
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( { - 1} \right)^n \frac{{\left( {\log n} \right)^{100} }}
{n}} 
$$
Now it is easy to see that the function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{{\left( {\log x} \right)^{100} }}
{x}
$$ 
with $x>1$ is

1. Positive.
2. Monotonic decreasing.
3. $
   \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f(x) = 0
   $

It follows that you can apply the Leibniz Test and your series is convergent.